# Side Column is Not going entire height

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am building a sidebar for my site and am trying to get it be the rest of the height of the page after the elements before it. I cannot figure out how to do it though. I am using bootstrap 4. But the problem is probably in my CSS, which I will post now.

```
.sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #212529;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}

#sidebar h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #fff;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    background: #212529;
    transition: all 0.3s
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    color: #c3c3c3;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
}

#sidebar ul li.active > a, a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}
ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}
```

My site that is having the trouble is actually live:
https://madewithloveandsarcasm.com/site/portfolio/

You can find all other pertinent code there. but the part I am really concerned with is the side bar

Comment: I don't know why exactly but removing the 100% from your .container fixes it.

I am guessing you are stretching something to be so large that it overflows the container and not adjusting the height.

Comment: You are a freaking genius man! Put the answer down! I want to give you the points for that, because I have been racking my brain for that.

Comment: Sure thing. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of why this is happening.

As you know percentage values depend on the parent, if the parent has say `height:50px;`
and a direct child has `height:50%` the child's height will equal `25px` because `50%` of `50px` is `25px`

However if the parent has `height:0` which is the default value, then `height:100%` will equal `0`  because `100%` of `0` is `0`.

`flexbox` doesn't set the height of the parent, it merely makes the children stretch to fill the available space.

Your wrapper's height is defined by the content, so when you say `height:100%` it follows the height of the content (in flex environment), now the content here is the `nav#sidebar` and `main`

main is higher so the parent's height will equal it's height which is defined by it's content (could be hard coded or even set by JS), `flexbox` will stretch the other children, now setting `height:100%` on a child means the height of the parent as if that child is the only one that exists, to see this remove the `main` element all together then `height:100%` will work, removing it works because like i said earlier `flexbox` do stretch the children.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the 100% from your .container to fix it. Apparently, this made them overflow their parent container and didn't adjust for height.